# Is it a good idea to sign a cookie that contains a JWT?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Should I sign cookies that contain JWT for authorization? Does signing cookies that contain JWT make the jwt unreadable by the user when they try to decode it using e.g. https://jwt.io/ and therefor making it more secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my limited experience with JWT, I would think the process of your signing and the JWT decoding are independant. But for the JWT to be valid, it is supposed to arrive on the server as it has been emitted (meaning as it has been signed). Beside JWT is not meant to keep a secret. You may be interested in checking these [tutorials about JWT](https://tutorama.info/CTG/JWT), where I myself learned a lot.

Comment: Okay thanks! I've come to the conclusion that I will not sign my cookies because it's just unnecessary since JWT are already signed so if the cookie gets tampered with the JWT will catch that so to speak, if I'm right